# How do I delete my notes on one device without deleting them from iCloud?

Tags: ios

A friend of mine bought a new iPhone yesterday and wants to give her old one as a hand-me-down. The retail guy transferred her contacts but not her notes.

Comment: Get your friend to read [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the iCloud from the device and the notes will/should disappear with it.

Comment: This is not sufficient. The device needs wiping entirely, otherwise it still belongs to its previous owner.

Comment: Not really. You can log in and out of different iCloud's on the same device through the settings, the only "lock" would be if Find my iPhone was left on for the old owner, but I'm pretty sure logging out through the settings would deactivate that as well. The apps on the device would remain under ownership of the other Apple account so it is recommended to wipe it because you won't be able to update "their" apps without their password.